# Reactjs form with multiple inputs and state change

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a ReactJS form to accept multiple input from the user and display it in an alert box. I am unable to display my data after the user has entered it.

**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
class Multiselect extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={ employee:'', fruit:'Apple'};
        this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit= this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({
    employee: event.target.empname,fruit:event.target.fruit});
    }
    handleSubmit(event){
        alert('Employee name is' +this.state.empname +"fruit selected is "+ this.state.fruit);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>Name
                    <input type="text" empname={this.state.empname} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </label>
                <select fruit={this.state.fruit} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <option fruit="Apple">Apple</option>
                    <option fruit="Mango">Mango</option>
                    <option fruit="Guava">Guava</option>
                    <option fruit="Orange">Orange</option>
                </select>
                <input type="Submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
export default Multiselect
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `input` and `select` props to `value` and the code should be like

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Multiselect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { employee: "", fruit: "Apple" };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert(
      "Employee name is" +
        this.state.employee +
        "fruit selected is " +
        this.state.fruit
    );
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name
          <input
            type="text"
            name="employee"
            value={this.state.empname}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <select
          value={this.state.fruit}
          name="fruit"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
          <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
          <option value="Guava">Guava</option>
          <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
        </select>
        <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default Multiselect;
```

You can check here: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-lehmann-rhcog